# Non async method returning Task<>

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would like to know if there is a difference between these two async patterns. Obviously they will work. I would like to know if there is a hidden trap or performance overhead. What will happen with aggregateexception call stack in both cases?

```
    //------Pattern1-------- PassThruMethod is awaiting
    public async void EventHandler()
    {
        await PassThruMethod();
    }

    public async Task<int> PassThruMethod()
    {
        return await MyAsyncMethod();
    }

    public Task<int> MyAsyncMethod()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 1);
    }


    //---Pattern2----- PassThruMethod is not awaiting
    public async void EventHandler()
    {
        await PassThruMethod();
    }

    public Task<int> PassThruMethod()
    {
        return MyAsyncMethod();
    }

    public Task<int> MyAsyncMethod()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `async` if you don't use `await` - since your `PassThruMethod` doesn't need `await`, don't use it. You can change it at any time if you eventually find out it's not good enough.

Using `await` does have some overhead (not exactly huge, but there is some), so for a case like this, there's no reason to use it. Returning `Task` is just fine.